# RegEx to find and escape apostrophe

Tags: regex

I'm having a regex melt down today. 2nd problem.
I wish to do a bulk insert of addresses to mySQL however I need to escape some apostrophes.
Does any one know the regex to use? - I'm using notepad++

This is personal on localhost so no chance of sql injection.

thanks

Comment: Give us some row on which you need to perform regex, and than what the regex should match. It's hard to provide help without your example of what you really need...

Comment: Thanks - Here's one entry where I'd like to escape the apostrophe - in L'Eglise. (32,'Craipso Productions',' 11 Place de L'Eglise
Vieux Thann
68800
FRANCE
),

Comment: So is the regex to be performed on just `L'Eglise` or on the whole string `(32,'Craipso Productions',' 11 Place de L'Eglise Vieux Thann 68800 FRANCE )` ? It would be a lot easier to do the regex on the simple string before building it into the field list.

Comment: the RegEx is to be performed on a whole load of insert values as above-I only want to find them when there is a letter before and after it.

Comment: Any reasonable database framework or SQL API should be providing you with a way to escape (or quote) a string to use in a query, so you shouldn't be doing it yourself. What programming language or database API are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that the apostrophes you're interested in are always surrounded by letters? In that case, searching for

```
\>'\<
```

and replacing with

```
\'
```

should work.

`\<` matches the start, `\>` matches the end of a word in Notepad++.

Comment: Yes that's correct - I only want to escape it when there is a letter before and after it.

Comment: So what happens if you try my solution?

Comment: One thing - is this particular case it is for mySQL inserts so I only need the one forward slash.

Comment: I'm sorry? Could you rephrase that, I don't understand what you're saying.