# I want to modify this regex to include apostrophe

Tags: regex

This regex is used for validating email addresses, however it doesn't include the case for apostrophy (') which is a valid character in the first part of an email address.
I have tried myself and to use some examples I found, but they don't work.

```
^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

How do I modify it slightly to support the ' character (apostraphy)?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [RegEx to find and escape apostrophe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746460/regex-to-find-and-escape-apostrophe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the documentation for an email address, the apostrophe can appear anywhere before the `@` symbol, which, in your current regex is:

```
^([\w-\.]+)@
```

You should be able to add the apostrophe into the brackets of valid characters:

```
^([\w-\.']+)@
```

This would make the entire regex:

```
^([\w-\.']+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

**EDIT** (regex contained in single-quotes)
If you're using this regex inside a string with single-quotes, such as in PHP with `$regex = '^([\w ...`, you will need to escape the single-quote in the regex with `\'`:

```
^([\w-\.\']+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the first part as follows:

```
^([\'\w-\.]+)
```